# Can I read an address (already written) from file into a pointer? Will it be useful?

Tags: c++

Say I write address of a struct in myFile.txt. Will I be able to read that address into my program? Will that address be useful?

Comment: Why would you do this in the first place?

Comment: The only time I can think of this being useful is if you are implementing a memory paging scheme...  But then, you'd be the OS kernel.

Comment: You can do that, but if the program closes even if you have the address the content will not be there and maybe you are going to try to access an protected area. It is best to serialize the struct into your file

Comment: Supposee a member function of a struct is pointer and I want to store this struct's object's data. How will be that possible?

Comment: Search for "boost serialization".  Essentially, you will have to come up with a scheme where the contents of the "pointed-to" structure is written and read from the file.

Answer (score 1):

A pointer is just a memory address. You can write it just fine, but when you read it, it is still just a memory address. Unless the object that it was pointing to is at the exact same memory location when you read it, you will be "reading" a pointer to random data, which you cannot convert to the class of the object it was pointing to before.

It's like storing the location (lat/long) of a butterfly, then trying to find that butterfly just from that position. The butterfly is most likley in a completely different place now.

Comment: Supposee a member function of a struct is pointer and I want to store this struct's object's data. How will the object be stored?

Answer (score 1):

1)You can write it.
2)You can read it.
3)If you read it back into the same instance of the program that wrote it, it has a real chance of being meaningful, depending on whether you have deleted the memory.

But generally it will be no use at all. Memory layout is free to changed from run to run, and memory you malloc/new on one run is not still waiting around when next you run the program.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it will be useful. When a program runs, it is loaded in memory. So now you write a text file of a struct. When the program terminates, the memory will be freed. Unless you are running two programs at the same time (one is writing the address and one other is reading), it will be useless, and may produce exception.

If you intend to use the struct value some other time, I think it is better to write the content of the struct and save it to a file, rather than the address. To write the content of a struct, you can try looking at how to write a binary file.

Comment: What if the content of struct is also a pointer? Now I'll have to write this pointer(adderss) and then read it later on?

Comment: even for two programs at same time doest work. Different program can be in their own virtual memory space.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it. Whether it will be useful or not depends on whether that address still contains any useful information. Generally speaking, it should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes,** but not for anything purposeful.

You can save it however you like, then read it back immediately, in the same process from which it came, as long as you haven't done something to invalidate the pointer.  That includes:

- Closing the process
- Freeing the memory the pointer points, if it's on the heap (from `new`, `malloc`, `HeapAlloc`, etc)
- Returning from the function, if it's on the stack (a local variable or parameter)

In other words, you can't do anything with it by saving it in a file that you couldn't do just by having the pointer to save in the first place.

Use files for persistent storage (i.e. state you need to keep when the process closes, invalidating all pointers) or as an abstraction for streams that share data between processes (i.e. can't share pointers anyway) and computers (i.e. can't share pointers anyway).  If you need to restore a structure from a previous run, save the structure in a file.  If you need to share it between processes, you can copy it by value via a file, or you are looking at a totally different set of kernel functions.  If you need to share it between computers, you have to copy it.

If you don't need any of that, **just use the pointer**.

Answer (score 0):

The structure or class should write its members to the file.
If the structure contains a pointer to another class, the container structure needs to tell the element structure to write itself to the file.

For example:

```
class Element
{
  public:  
    ostream& write_to_file(ostream& output_file);
};

class Container
{
  public:
    ostream& write_to_file(ostream& output_file)
    {
      return contained_element.write_to_file(output_file);
    }
  private:
    Element contained_element;
};
```

The rule is that a class knows the members it has.  The class is a good candidate for writing its members to a file; not some external mechanism.